Setting prefab true in Android Studio leads to some files being reported as "This file is not part of the project."
add this code in build.gradle file
  buildFeatures {
        prefab true
    }

some of source file show This file is not part of the project. Please ...
but 'gradle assembleRelease' could build the project success
some of version:
android.prefabVersion=2.1.0
android studio version 2023.2.1 Patch 1
cmake version 3.28.2
try:
change prefabVersion from 2.0.0 2.1.0
change gredle verion
change cmake version
change android studio version
